# Access registered com object from wcf webservice

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, com

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS 7, this service use a COM object to communicate with some devices. In my PC this works, but when I install the web service in the production server the COM object creation fails. The dll containing the COM object is already registered, I know that because another process use the same reference and it works (the WCF service purpose is take the place of the another process) however, the WCF service is unable to instantiate the COM object. I already re-registered the dll using regsvr32. In my development PC this works, but when I install the web service the object creation fails.

Why the WCF service cannot create the COM instance?

Comment: Maybe 32/64 bits issues? Maybe the identity used by the apppool has no permission? What is the specific error/exception/eventlog message?

Comment: Thanks @rene, I checked the Application pool in IIS and the 32-bit applications was disabled.